# 'UnityShim' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How Can I Solve This Error?
Assets\Inkyu\Assets\Plugins\GitHub\Editor\UnityAPIWrapper.cs(15,18): error CS0103: The name 'UnityShim' does not exist in the current context

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace GitHub.Unity
{
    [InitializeOnLoad]
    public class UnityAPIWrapper : ScriptableSingleton<UnityAPIWrapper>
    {
        static UnityAPIWrapper()
        {
#if UNITY_2018_2_OR_NEWER
             Editor.finishedDefaultHeaderGUI += editor => {
                 UnityShim.Raise_Editor_finishedDefaultHeaderGUI(editor);
             };
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this namespace `Unity.VersionControl.Git` like

```
using Unity.VersionControl.Git;
```

[Ref](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Git-for-Unity/blob/master/src/com.unity.git.ui/Shim/UnityShim.cs)